# what is EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (sigill)? Why is it caused?

Tags: xcode, macos, exc-bad-access, freetype

My application file works fine on my mac, the problem is  when i try and install it on client's machine.

In the crash report I see that functions from libfreetype.dylib are causing the crash.

Is it because I have ported an incompatible dylib to client's machine? because when i compiled freetype using brew I used -**universal** flag.

Both the machines are Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 2):

Your client machine is probably an older hardware.
Brew builds optimised code for your machine's processor by default.
This will result in occasional SIGILL when that code is run on older hardware that doesnt have the newer instruction set used for optimization.

For distrubution, you should:

**brew install --build-bottle freetype**

for that and any other libraries that you ship from brew